# Metrics for Kubernetes events which are stored in apiserver

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kube-apiserver

I was trying to look out for metrics or exporters which could provide information about Kubernetes events which are stored in apiserver.

Read things here:

https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/kube_apiserver_metrics/

https://www.sumologic.com/blog/how-to-monitor-kubernetes/

I could not find anything relevant to my use case.

Any help around this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you can check the prometheus operator, it can be installed using helm

Comment: @c4f4t0r could you redirect me to any blog or documentation which will have the relevant metrics?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @c4f4t0r you should implement the Prometheus Operator.

Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator) regarding this.

> Installs prometheus-operator to create/configure/manage Prometheus
>   clusters atop Kubernetes. This chart includes multiple components and
>   is suitable for a variety of use-cases.
>
> The default installation is intended to suit monitoring a kubernetes
>   cluster the chart is deployed onto. It closely matches the
>   kube-prometheus project.
>
> prometheus-operator prometheus alertmanager node-exporter
>   kube-state-metrics grafana service monitors to scrape internal
>   kubernetes components kube-apiserver kube-scheduler
>   kube-controller-manager etcd kube-dns/coredns kube-proxy With the
>   installation, the chart also includes dashboards and alerts.

And here are some more details regarding [Prometheus Operator vs. kube-prometheus vs. community helm chart](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator) if you are interested.

Please let me know if that helped.